# Displaying polygon shapes from the set of coordinates to around the markers

Tags: google-maps, jquery, google-maps-api-3, maps

I'm implementing to display the shapes from the set of coordinates around the markers. Here is my html and js code but seems to be not working and I'hv missed some thing in this. Please help me to solve this.

And also how to get the below coordinates from the same XML file and create array to draw shapes and makes it center.

```
 var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(17.74033553, 83.25067267);

     var triangleCoords = [
              new google.maps.LatLng(17.74033553, 83.25067267),
              new google.maps.LatLng(17.73254774, 83.29195094),
              new google.maps.LatLng(17.73995296, 83.25317370),
              new google.maps.LatLng(17.73985100, 83.25417283),

                new google.maps.LatLng(17.73420624, 83.29552820),
                  new google.maps.LatLng(17.74752536, 83.24668705)
          ];
```

Html Code :

```
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head runat="server">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/en/js/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="/en/js/markers.js">
              </script>
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div id="map">
            </div>
            <input type="button" id="showmarkers" value="Show Markers" />
            </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

js Code to display markers and shapes arround.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#map").css({
                height: 500,
                width: 600
            });
            var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(17.74033553, 83.25067267);
            MYMAP.init('#map', myLatLng, 11);

            $("#showmarkers").click(function (e) {
                MYMAP.placeMarkers('markers.xml');
            });
        });

        var MYMAP = {
            map: null,
            bounds: null
        }

        MYMAP.init = function (selector, latLng, zoom) {
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: zoom,
                center: latLng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            this.map = new google.maps.Map($(selector)[0], myOptions);
            this.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        }

        MYMAP.placeMarkers = function (filename) {
            $.get(filename, function (xml) {
                $(xml).find("marker").each(function () {
                    var name = $(this).find('name').text();
                    var address = $(this).find('address').text();

                    // create a new LatLng point for the marker
                    var lat = $(this).find('lat').text();
                    var lng = $(this).find('lng').text();
                    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat), parseFloat(lng));

                    // extend the bounds to include the new point
                    MYMAP.bounds.extend(point);
                    var triangleCoords = [
              new google.maps.LatLng(17.74033553, 83.25067267),
              new google.maps.LatLng(17.73254774, 83.29195094),
              new google.maps.LatLng(17.73995296, 83.25317370),
              new google.maps.LatLng(17.73985100, 83.25417283),

                new google.maps.LatLng(17.73420624, 83.29552820),
                  new google.maps.LatLng(17.74752536, 83.24668705)
          ];



                    // Construct the polygon
                    bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
                        paths: triangleCoords,
                        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                        strokeWeight: 2,
                        fillColor: '#FF0000',
                        fillOpacity: 0.35
                    });


                    bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: point,
                        map: MYMAP.map
                    });

                    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                    var html = '<strong>' + name + '</strong.><br />' + address;
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                        infoWindow.setContent(html);
                        infoWindow.open(MYMAP.map, marker);
                    });
                    MYMAP.map.fitBounds(MYMAP.bounds);
                });
            });
        }
```

XMl file

```
 <markers>
        <marker>
        <name>VODAFONE</name>
        <address>near Ghumaghumalu Restaurant, Marripalem, Visakhapatnam</address>
        <lat>17.74033553</lat>
        <lng>83.25067267</lng>
        </marker>

        <marker>
        <name>VODAFONE</name>
        <address>near Viswa Teja School, Thatichetlapalem, Visakhapatnam</address>
        <lat>17.73254774</lat>
        <lng>83.29195094</lng>
        </marker>

        <marker>
        <name>VODAFONE</name>
        <address>near Masjid, Marripalem, Visakhapatnam</address>
        <lat>17.73995296</lat>
        <lng>83.25317370</lng>
        </marker>

        <marker>
        <name>VODAFONE</name>
        <address>near Masjid, Sai Nagar, Visakhapatnam</address>
        <lat>17.73985100</lat>
        <lng>83.25417283</lng>
        </marker>

        <marker>
        <name>VODAFONE</name>
        <address>near Sai Baba Temple, Akkayya Palem, Visakhapatnam</address>
        <lat>17.73420624</lat>
        <lng>83.29552820</lng>
        </marker>

        <marker>
        <name>VODAFONE</name>
        <address>near Geological Survey of India, R &amp; B, Visakhapatnam</address>
        <lat>17.74752536</lat>
        <lng>83.24668705</lng>
        </marker>



        </markers>
```

----------- Below is the Working js code to just display markers but the above js file is to display markers and polygon shape.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#map").css({
        height: 500,
        width: 600
    });
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(17.74033553, 83.25067267);
  MYMAP.init('#map', myLatLng, 11);

  $("#showmarkers").click(function(e){
        MYMAP.placeMarkers('markers.xml');
  });
});

var MYMAP = {
  map: null,
    bounds: null
}

MYMAP.init = function(selector, latLng, zoom) {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom:zoom,
    center: latLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  this.map = new google.maps.Map($(selector)[0], myOptions);
    this.bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
}

MYMAP.placeMarkers = function(filename) {
    $.get(filename, function(xml){
        $(xml).find("marker").each(function(){
            var name = $(this).find('name').text();
            var address = $(this).find('address').text();

            // create a new LatLng point for the marker
            var lat = $(this).find('lat').text();
            var lng = $(this).find('lng').text();
            var point = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(lat),parseFloat(lng));

            // extend the bounds to include the new point
            MYMAP.bounds.extend(point);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: point,
                map: MYMAP.map
            });

            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
            var html='<strong>'+name+'</strong.><br />'+address;
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(html);
                infoWindow.open(MYMAP.map, marker);
            });
            MYMAP.map.fitBounds(MYMAP.bounds);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Is there any error you are facing.

Comment: Yes, it wont display markers and shapes but if you remove coordinates of displaying line from the above js file, then it will display markers but I want to display the polyline along with markers too.Thanks for head up on this

Comment: I mean if you remove the  // Construct the polygon sections it will work fine. Note I just edited by my first post with working js code to display markers but it wont display shape from the set of coordinates.

Comment: What are you trying to do? use the coordinates of the markers in the XML file to create a Polygon _also_ or have a Polygon defined in the XML that displays in addition to the markers?

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs here:

```
bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
```

A variable map isn't defined somewhere, so the browser uses(when available) an element with the ID "map" as `map`-variable instead(unfortunately most browsers did implement this bad behaviour introduced by IE). The result is an error because `setMap` expects as argument a `google.maps.Map`-instance, not a `DOMNode` .

the line should be:

```
bermudaTriangle.setMap(MYMAP.map);
```

....and your script will work.

Comment: I need an urgent help to create the set of array coordinates dynamically to display the polygon around the markers. The below code needs to be generate  dynamically from the XML. Please have a look at it var triangleCoords = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(51.055221725218054, -3.1630325317382812),
    new google.maps.LatLng(51.010961025187314, -3.1359100341796875),
    new google.maps.LatLng(51.043135193868025, -3.063812255859375)

  ];